# .append(data) to all <input type="email">

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, each

Hello stackoverflow users,

How can I use `.append(data)` to only 1 `<input type="email">`?

Cuz I tried `.each()` with the documentation of `jquery.com` but it isn't realy clear to me yet.

What I have now is;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input#email").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checklistHandler.php?action=valEmail",
            data: $("input#email")
        }).done(function(data){
            $("span.emailCheck").empty().append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my form I have 2 times the `<input type="email">`, but when I fill in only the first one, it should only check the first `<input type="email">`.
But it checks all the `<input type="email">`.

Hope you people can help me!

Greets.

[UPDATE 1]

```
<input style="min-width: 212px; max-width: 212px;" type="email" id="email"      name="buildingblock[<?=$onderdeel['formBuildingBlockId']?>][content]" value="<?= $onderdeel['formContent'] ?>" <?=($onderdeel['formRequired'] == 'on' ? 'required' : '')?>><span class="emailCheck"></span>
```

[UPDATE 2]

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "valEmail") {
foreach ($_POST['buildingblock'] as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value['content'])) {
        ?>
        <img src="<?=IMG?>/cross.png">
        <p style="background-color: red; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; border-radius: 4px;">Het E-Mail veld mag niet leeg zijn!</p>
        <?
    } else {
        if (!preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $value['content'])) {
            ?>
            <img src="<?=IMG?>/cross.png">
            <p style="background-color: red; text-align: center; color:white; border-radius: 4px;">Dit is geen geldig E-Mail adres</p>
            <?
        } else {
            ?>
            <img src="<?=IMG?>/tick.png">
            <?
        }
    }
    return;
}
exit();
}
```

Comment: share your html code

Comment: `data: $("input#email").val()` instead of `data: $("input#email")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this in post method [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

change to `data: $("input#email").val()`

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checklistHandler.php?action=valEmail",
        data: $("input#email") // change here  $("input#email").val()
    }).done(function(data){
        $("span.emailCheck").empty().append(data);
    });
```

Comment: I don't think you realy get what I mean :(

Comment: But I use PHP to get the data!

Comment: What was the problem ?

Comment: The check it shows it at all the inputs with the type email. But it should only show it at the input with the email where you are typing in!

Answer (score 0):

check below code . use  data: $(this).val(). also if value is blank then it will not execute ajax code.

```
 $(document).off('keyup').on('keyup',"input[type='email']",function(){
   if($.trim($(this).val()).length > 0){ 
     var obj = $(this); 
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checklistHandler.php?action=valEmail",
        data : obj.val(),
    }).done(function(data){
        obj.next("span.emailCheck").empty().append(data);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The form is inside the a  foreach!

Comment: script also inside loop?

Comment: Nope doing nothing anymore now

Comment: which version of jquery you use?

Comment: The latest! like the link that is always the latest

Comment: is it give any error in console? i have apply small change in my code

Comment: it says that the action is oke.